# Self Hosted Maximum URL length

Tags: servicestack

While self hosting an application derived from AppSelfHostBase, I'm running into an issue where I get an invalid url error if the parameter list gets too long.  Is there a config setting that is causing this?

```
[<Route("/Accounts/UserId/{user_id}", "GET")>]
type GetAccountsByUserId() =
    interface IReturn<GetAccountsByUserIdResponse>
    member val user_id = [||]:int array with get, set
```

Here is the sample of the url that is causing the error

/Accounts/UserId/2133,2937,2235,6499,6502,6761,6760,740,838,6160,856,6778,7691,143,2536,1921,4150,6438,2882,6196,1716,1046,1744,6288,6266,2775,166,673,196,205,220,142,260,266,333,672,469,761,775,877,1059,2239,2590,367,369,372,496,917,1708,2274,2275,1377,1752,6636,6637,6638,2281?format=json

The result is

Bad Request - Invalid URL
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.